# How can I improve the performance of this stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, stored-procedures

Okay so I made some changes to a stored procedure that we have, and it now takes 3 hours to run (it used to only take 10 minutes before). I have a temp table called `#tCustomersEmail`.  In it, is a column called `OrderDate`, which has a lot of null values in it. I want to replace those null values with data from another database on a different server. So here's what I have:

I create another temp table:

```
Create Table #tSouth
(
CustID char(10),
InvcDate nchar(10)
)
```

Which I populate with this data:

```
INSERT INTO #tSouth(CustID, InvcDate)
SELECT DISTINCT
      [CustID],
      max(InvcDate) as InvcDate
  FROM D3.SouthW.dbo.uc_InvoiceLine I
  where EXISTS (SELECT CustomerNumber FROM #tCustomersEmail H WHERE   I.CustID =  H.CustomerNumber) 
  group BY I.CustID
```

Then I take the data from `#tSouth` and update the `OrderDate` in the `#tCustomersEmail` table, as long as the `CustomerNumber` matches up, and the `OrderDate` is null:

```
UPDATE #tCustomersEmail  
SET OrderDate = InvcDate 
FROM #tCustomersEmail  
INNER JOIN #tSouth ON #tCustomersEmail.CustomerNumber = [#tSouth].CustID
where #tCustomersEmail.OrderDate IS null
```

Making those changes caused the stored procedure to take FOR-EV-ER (Sandlot reference!)

So what am I doing wrong?

BTW I create indexes on my temp tables after I create them  like so:

```
create clustered index idx_Customers ON #tCustomersEmail(CustomerNumber)
CREATE clustered index idx_CustSouthW ON #tSouth(CustID)
```

Comment: Why all the temp tables? If you are overusing these, you will have a bottleneck with your tempdb.

Comment: Because I cant put indexes on the real tables.

Comment: Are you creating the temp tables **inside** your stored proc?? That could cause the proc to be recompiled - several times over....

Comment: Yes I'm creating my temp tables in the SP.

Comment: Is there an index on D3.SouthW.dbo.uc_InvoiceLine.CustID ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try skipping the #tsouth table and use this query:

```
UPDATE a
SET OrderDate = (select max(InvcDate) from D3.SouthW.dbo.uc_InvoiceLine I 
                 where a.customernumber = custid)  
FROM #tCustomersEmail a  
WHERE orderdate is null
```

I don't think the index will help you in this example

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as the solution, because it took the least amount of time to run.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use table variable instead of temp table?

```
declare @temp table
(
    CustID char(10),
    InvcDate nchar(10)
)

insert into @temp
...
```

That definitely will increase the performance!

Answer (score 2):

Distinct isn't needed if you have a GROUP BY.  Given you are going across database I don't like the EXISTS.  I would change that part to limit the number of rows at that point. Change to:

```
INSERT INTO #tSouth(CustID, InvcDate)
SELECT 
      [CustID],
      max(InvcDate) as InvcDate
  FROM D3.SouthW.dbo.uc_InvoiceLine I
  where I.CustID in 
       (SELECT CustomerNumber 
        FROM #tCustomersEmail H 
        WHERE H.OrderDate IS null ) 
  group BY I.CustID
```

EDIT: Looking closer are you sure uc_InvoiceLine should be used?  Looks like there should be a parent table to that one that would had the date and have fewer rows.
Also, you can skip the one temp table by doing the update directly:

```
UPDATE #tCustomersEmail  
SET OrderDate = InvcDate 
FROM #tCustomersEmail  
INNER JOIN (SELECT 
      [CustID],
      max(InvcDate) as InvcDate
  FROM D3.SouthW.dbo.uc_InvoiceLine I
  where I.CustID in 
       (SELECT CustomerNumber 
        FROM #tCustomersEmail H 
        WHERE H.OrderDate IS null ) 
  group BY I.CustID) Invoices
ON #tCustomersEmail.CustomerNumber = Invoices.CustID
```

Comment: The uc_Invoice line is the table i need my info from.  Its a non-normalized database.  I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The reason I created the #tSouth, was so that i could put an index on it, since there is no primary key.  Is your way of updating still faster?

Comment: Not sure how many rows you are talking about.  I like that the OrderDate is now applied before bringing rows back from the other DB - I think that is what will correct your performance problem.

Comment: I'm dealing with millions of rows in each table.

Comment: Yeah I'm still waiting for it to run.  Its at 40 minutes.  If it stays under an hour, I'll be happy.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to predict the behaviour of complex queries involving tables on a linked server, because the local server has no access to statistics for the remote table,  and can end up with a poor query plan because of this - it will work on the assumption that the remote table has either 1 or 100 rows.
If this wasn't bad enough, the result of the bad plan can be to pull the entire remote table over the wire into local temp space and work on it there. If the remote table is very large, this can be a major performance overhead.

In might be worth trying to simplify the linked server query to minimise the chances of the entire table being returned over the wire - (as has already been mentioned, you don't need both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`)

```
INSERT INTO #tSouth(CustID, InvcDate)
SELECT [CustID],
      max(InvcDate) as InvcDate
  FROM D3.SouthW.dbo.uc_InvoiceLine I
  group BY I.CustID
```

leaving the rest of the query unchanged.

However, because of the aggregate this may still bring the whole table back to the local server - you'll need to test to find out. Your best bet may be to encapsulate this logic in a view in the SouthW database, if you're able to create objects in it, then reference that from your SP code.